# How delay and loop while flag is false?

Tags: java

I need add delay to execution for another method async
and  enter in a loop when flag is false

```
boolean flag = false;

if flag == false > add delay, and try again

if flag == true > stop delay and return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand this example

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean delay = true;
        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            if(delay == true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);//time in millisecond, here 1000 = 1second
                counter++;
                System.out.println("counter is now: " + counter);
            }
            if(delay == false) {
                break;
            }
            if(counter == 10) {
                delay = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: perfect, it is what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the example by @shivam7357:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean delay = true;
        int counter = 0;
        while (delay) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);//time in millisecond, here 1000 = 1second
            counter++;
            System.out.println("counter is now: " + counter);

            if(counter == 10) {
                delay = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

In this example, the while loop will not proceed if `delay` is false. So all you need to do is sleep the thread, then check if the counter is high enough to set `delay` to false, thereby breaking out of the while loop.

Comment: I also like this example

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.sleep(1000);`, [here's an example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)